# libmysql mysql_real_connect fails with IP address but works with localhost

Tags: c++, mysql

Okay so my issue is pretty straight forward, I am relatively new to C++ so this may be an easy answer for some, but I am using libmysql to connect to a database and so far it works just as I need it too. But I want to be able to connect to a database not found at local host, the database will still be on my LAN but just not on the local machine. I am pretty sure that the `unix_socket` parameter is all that i need to change but i have no clue how or what to change it to or how to make a "unix_socket". Below i will post my code and thank you in advanced for help thanks!

```
void readFromDB(){
skip:
     MYSQL *connect; // Create a pointer to the MySQL instance
connect=mysql_init(NULL); // Initialise the instance
/* This If is irrelevant and you don't need to show it. I kept it in for Fault Testing.*/
if(!connect)    /* If instance didn't initialize say so and exit with fault.*/
{
    fprintf(stderr,"MySQL Initialization Failed");


}
/* Now we will actually connect to the specific database.*/

connect=mysql_real_connect(connect,"10.1.3.253",USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE,3306, NULL,0);
/* Following if statements are unneeded too, but it's worth it to show on your
first app, so that if your database is empty or the query didn't return anything it
will at least let you know that the connection to the mysql server was established. */

if(connect){
    printf("First Connection Succeeded\n");
            system("PAUSE");
}
else{
    printf("Connection Failed!\n");
            Sleep(800);
            goto skip;
}
MYSQL_RES *result; /* Create a pointer to recieve the return value.*/
MYSQL_ROW row;  /* Assign variable for rows. */

//mysql_query(connect,"SELECT * FROM locationTime");
/* Send a query to the database. */
    if(!(mysql_query(connect,"SELECT * FROM locationtime") == 0)){
            mysql_close(connect);
            Sleep(300);
            goto skip;
    }
result = mysql_store_result(connect); /* Receive the result and store it in res_set */


unsigned int numrows = mysql_num_rows(result); /* Create the count to print all rows */

/* This while is to print all rows and not just the first row found, */
    if(numrows != 0){
            while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)) != NULL){
                    ids.push_back(row[0]);
                    dateTime.push_back(row[1]);
                    locs.push_back(setLocation(row[2]));
                    strLocs.push_back(row[2]);
                    imgPaths.push_back(row[3]);

                    //for(int i = 0; i<(sizeof(row)  ); i++){
                    //        //printf("%s\n",row[i] != NULL ? row[i] : "NULL"); /* Print the     row data */
                    //}
                    //cout<<endl<<endl;
            }
    }else if(numrows <= 0){
            mysql_close(connect);   /* Close and shutdown */
            mysql_free_result(result);
            Sleep(200);
            goto skip;
    }
mysql_close(connect);   /* Close and shutdown */
    mysql_free_result(result);
return;
}
```

and here is my header file:

```
#include "my_global.h" // Include this file first to avoid problems
#include "mysql.h" // MySQL Include File
#define SERVER "10.1.3.253"
#define USER "user"
#define PASSWORD "pass"
#define DATABASE "DBName"
```

Comment: Why are you using the C module in C++ when there's a [C++ library](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/) that's a lot better?

Comment: I could not figure out how to use it. All the documentation for it I could find was not very good and like I said I am new to this language so I was not sure how to implement it and that module seemed very simple and straightforward

Comment: I'm just giving you a heads up that using the raw C library is really, really annoying and not just because of the extra work involved in correctly manipulating C-style strings. If you can use a library like [SQL API](http://www.sqlapi.com/) you'll probably avoid most of this. The documentation for the basic C++ adapter isn't great, but you'd probably have an easier time figuring that out than debugging your C database code.

Comment: Okay well thank you for the heads up, I need all the pointers (no pun intended) that i can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually if you're having a problem connecting via IP it's that your user account is not allowed to connect from a "remote" address.

Normally this is fixed by:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `user`@`%` IDENTIFIED BY '...'
```

Where `user` is your username. You may want to lock down access more, obviously.

`localhost` is what's used for "local" connections via UNIX socket. All others are treated as remote.

Comment: you sir are awesome, Id have been screwing with this crap all day thinking it was something with my code, i have experience with mysql and PHP and i never even thought of looking at the privileges, this is why i love stack overflow! thanks so so much can't believe it was this simple